# RAID-5 inoperable, but no disk failure

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, 3ware

Inheritted a system with a 3ware LSI 9750-8i having five disks and RAID-5.
I see a message about "*RAID-5 INOPERABLE*" for u1 but see no disk failure for the only disk (p1) in the unit.

```
Unit  UnitType  Status         %RCmpl  %V/I/M  Stripe  Size(GB)  Cache  AVrfy
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
u0    RAID-5    OK             -       -       256K    5587.9    RiW    ON
u1    RAID-5    INOPERABLE     -       -       256K    5587.9    Ri     ON

VPort Status         Unit Size      Type  Phy Encl-Slot    Model
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
p0    OK             u0   1.82 TB   SATA  0   -            WDC WD2000FYYZ-01UL
p1    OK             u1   1.82 TB   SATA  1   -            WDC WD2003FYYS-02W0
p2    OK             u0   1.82 TB   SATA  2   -            WDC WD2003FYYS-02W0
p3    OK             u0   1.82 TB   SATA  3   -            WDC WD2003FYYS-02W0
p4    OK             u0   1.82 TB   SATA  4   -            WDC WD2000FYYZ-01UL

Name  OnlineState  BBUReady  Status    Volt     Temp     Hours  LastCapTest
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
bbu   On           Yes       OK        OK       OK       127    xx-xxx-xxxx
```

I don't quite get what is going on here and I am not seeing any errors in the logs or the operation of the system either.

I suspect that u1/p1 is the spare. Am I right? Do I need to replace the p1 disk and rebuild the u1 array?   Or just try to rebuild the u1 array?

The User Guide I have, is silent about what to do in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `u1` disk is a leftover from another RAID5 array, so the controller *detect* it but can clearly not activate it. To use that disk as a spare, you need to first clear the RAID config on `u1` disk and then re-add that disk to the array (as a spare).

Before doing anything, be sure to study the controller docs *and to have current, valid backups*

Comment: I concur with the left-over possibility.

Comment: @shodanshok, thank you. Do you mean "first clear the RAID config" of u1 or clear the *entire* controller (both units) and rebuild? I would prefer to delete it completely and add p1 as a spare to the working array.

Comment: The "it" in "clear the RAID config on it" is most certainly the "u1" disk. The RAID hardware I've used has little (if any) state you could clear. The state is written somewhere on the disk itself.

Comment: @G.D'Seas I was obviously referring to the `u1` disk. I'll edit my answer to be more clear.